# How can I compile tsschecker for Windows?

Tags: c, compilation, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile the C program [tsschecker](https://github.com/s0uthwest/tsschecker) for Windows(on my Mac). I installed `mingw-w64` with `brew install mingw-w64`, but I'm not sure how to use it to compile the program for Windows.

The Github repo for tsschecker includes instructions to compile for macOS and Linux(using `make`), but not Windows(but it includes Windows in the compatibility list).

I have access to a Windows machine if needed.

How can I compile tsschecker for Windows?

Comment: have you tried something like  [this] (https://gist.github.com/cosmo0920/45f5f5cdb6faeb27100d) because usually you have to install not only mingw-64 cross-compilers but also win-specific binutils/resource compilers and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GitHub Actions script to build binaries for Windows and Linux at [1Conan/tsschecker](https://github.com/1Conan/tsschecker) and there are prebuilt binaries at [releases](https://github.com/1Conan/tsschecker/releases).